# How to pass page variable in URL string upon click

Tags: dynamic-linking, linking, dynamic, encoding, link-info

I have a link to a 3rd party page, and I want the link to capture a unique customer number in the data/page and show it in my url string. Does Tridian use brackets to capture data in a URL or some other method? I'm trying to grab customer_no below. Thoughts?

Ex
[www.mywebpage1.com?tag.csp={{customer_no}}](http://www.mywebpage1.com?tag.csp=%7B%7Bcustomer_no%7D%7D)

Answer (score 2):

Tridion does not offer this feature, because it is a content management system, not a web application. You should implement this in the application which consumes the data from Tridion.